# Is this sentence grammatically correct? Present + Past Tense

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, tense, past-simple, present-simple

Could you please tell me if this sentence is correct?

I understood what the components of a pc are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a native speaker with a perfect 9 IELTS score. I think thats perfectly correct IF you are saying that you fully understood at some point in the past what the components parts of a PC (still) are. You might be meaning to add ("*but I have forgotten since then*")

caveat : If you are talking about a time 15 years ago (for example) and you think the components might have changed a little in minor details) then you might indicate this by saying  "I understood what the components of a pc **were** (then)"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it really helps me, as a non-native english speaker.